# Caching a linked list - is it possible?

Tags: c++, c, caching, memory-management, memory-alignment

I know that arrays may fully exploit the caching mechanisms on a x86_64 architecture by fitting into cache lines and because of their sequential nature. A linked list is a series of structs/objects linked together by pointers, is it possible to take advantage of the caching system with such a structure? Linked list's objects may be allocated anywhere in memory

Comment: You can if you implement your linked list using an array :)

Comment: @Nick You mean by storing pointers into an array?

Comment: No, by storing everything in the array. But I'm not sure it would be very helpful...

Comment: Yes - Just rewrite the new operator for linked lists.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Nick it's just a curiosity question, I could incur in such a problem one day

Comment: Using an array is pretty cache-friendly (and it's the only way if your language doesn't have pointers) - just use the index of the next element as the "next pointer". (A pointer is just an array index anyway, if you consider RAM as a huge array of bytes.) If you want something more flexible space-wise, use a `std::vector` instead of an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true that linked list entries *can* be anywhere, but they don't *have* to be "just anywhere".  For instance, you can allocate them out of a "zone".  Allocate a bunch of contiguous entries at one time, string them together into a list of "free entries that are contiguous", and then parcel them out.  Allocate another zone-full as needed.  With some not-very-clean tricks you can eventually re-linearize freed entries, and so on.

Most of the time it's not actually worth going to all this effort, though.

Comment: +1 for the last line! Especially if the most frequently accessed elements in the linked list are distributed evenly in the list.

Comment: @Nick: Yes -- and probably if this sort of tricky stuff gains much, a change in data structure would gain more. :-)

Comment: I agree with both of you, but I +1'd everyone who spent time answering my question. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple entries per linked list element, i.e. a small array of entries in each element. This allows caching of a few entries whilst still maintaining the dynamic nature of the list.

This is an [unrolled list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrolled_linked_list) and sort of gives you what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably have one element of linked list to contain more than 1 data entry.
e.g. consider below struct.

```
struct myll{
    int data[16];
    char valid[16/8];
    struct myll* next;
}
```

This way, you are making the granularity as 16 entries per node. However, you still have an option to add more entries than 16, using another node & delete using "valid" flag. It's a bit painful to implement, but depends on your requirement.

I guess, *somewhat similar* mechanism is used for some file systems.